# Динамическое создание объектов класса в конструкторе

Tags: c++, конструктор

Интересует вопрос: каким образом можно динамически заполнить вектор объектами дочерних классов в цикле, в конструкторе произвольного класса?

Например:

```
class Parent {
   public:
      //различные виртуальные функции
};

class Child1 : public Parent{
   public:
      //объявления функций
};

class Child2 : public Parent{
   public:
      //объявления функций
};

class SomeClass{
   public:
   std::vector<Parent*> vec;
   Child1 obj1;
   Child2 obj2;
   SomeClass(); 
};

SomeClass::SomeClass(){
   vec.push_back(&obj1);
   vec.push_back(&obj2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте инициализацию в теле класса:

```
class SomeClass{
public:
   Child1 obj1;
   Child2 obj2;
   std::vector<Parent*> vec{&obj1, &obj2};

   SomeClass() {}
};
```

Comment: лучше конструктору передать список инициализации и потом вектору присвоить всех объектов с помощью итераторов. неизвестно же ведь сколько объектов должно быть в векторе

Comment: @ampawd передать в конструктор указатели на члены конструируемого объекта? :)

Comment: @alexolut создавать эти дочерные объекты снаружи и передавать конструктору указатели `SomeClass` в виде `std::initialization_list<Parent*>`

Answer (score 3):

Если набор членов типа `ChildN` предполагается расширять в классе `SomeClass`, то их имена придется вручную дублировать при добавлении в вектор. Дублирование чревато ошибками. Поэтому предлагаю рассмотреть вариант вообще убрать члены `ChildN` из класса, а в векторе хранить владеющие указатели:

1. `std::unique_ptr`:

   ```
   struct SomeClass {
       std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> vec;
       SomeClass() {
           vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child1>());
           vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child2>());
      }; 
   };
   ```
2. `std::shared_ptr`:

   ```
   struct SomeClass {
       std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Parent>> vec { 
           std::make_shared<Child1>(), 
           std::make_shared<Child2>() 
       };
   };
   ```